# Populate javascript variable and then load scripts

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, square

In my MVC application, I'm trying to populate two javascript variables before loading a script. But I keep getting the error that my variables aren;t set before the javascript file loads. I've been going in circles trying to figure this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var applicationId = "@Constants.SquareUpPaymentInfo.AppID";
            var locationId = "@Constants.SquareUpPaymentInfo.LocationID";
            jQuery.getScript('https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform')
                .done(function () {
                    jQuery.getScript('@Url.Content("~/Content/JS/sqpaymentform.js")')
                        .fail(function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        })
                })
                .fail(
                function () {
                        alert('There was a connection issue for the payment form library. ');
                    });
        });
</script>
```

The sqpaymentform.js loads but it requires applicationID and locationID to be set but it thinks that they are not set for some reason but I can easily see that they are set in the chrome developer screen.

Comment: try moving your function declarations outside of `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `applicationId` and `locationId` as local variables. The script needs them to be global variables, so declare them outside the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var applicationId = "@Constants.SquareUpPaymentInfo.AppID";
var locationId = "@Constants.SquareUpPaymentInfo.LocationID";

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.getScript('https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform')
    .done(function() {
      jQuery.getScript('@Url.Content("~/Content/JS/sqpaymentform.js")')
        .fail(function() {
          alert('Failed');
        })
    })
    .fail(
      function() {
        alert('There was a connection issue for the payment form library. ');
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That seems to be the iteration that I didn't try. Thanks a million. Now I just have to figure why the paymentform library is no longer doing its thing and putting designated inputs inside of iframes. It's like it's loading but not executing.